# React Native WebView: can it show a url that needs VPN?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, vpn

I have a URL that runs locally on a remote server, e.g. 192.168.15.4/index.html, outside of my local network.

I use a VPN (pptp) connection to run it on my browser. This works OK in both my desktop Chrome and my Android Chrome (through the "Android VPN" feature).

Unfortunately, I cannot see this page when I add it as `source uri` inside a "React Native WebView", even though the phone's VPN is connected.

Do I need to do something extra on the Android (and iOS) part of my React Native app, in order for the url to be shown?

Comment: Hello!
It is been a while but, any way, did you managed how to handle this? I am facing the same problem here!